# react-native run-android not detecting emulator or device

Tags: android, react-native

When I run `react-native run-android` to run my React Native app I get this error and then the build fails:

```
'C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
```

I get this error whether I run the command with my phone connect by USB or if I run it with the emulator open from Android Studio. However, when I run `adb devices` both the emulator and my device show up.
I am pretty sure it is not a problem with the React Native code because I have tried running multiple different apps and get the same error.

Does anyone know what could be the problem and why the device and emulator aren't detected?

Comment: could you please post the output of `react-native info`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my computer's antivirus had deleted adb.exe so once I reinstalled the platform tools folder containing adb.exe, `react-native run-android` worked as normal and my connected device was detected.